# How many integers $(n)$ are there where $n + 30$ is a multiple of $2n$?

Tags: puzzle

I tried to write an equation for the problem but really got stuck with something like $n + 30 = 2n × x$

Comment: Hint: Write the problem statement in equation form, and isolate the variables to the other side of the equation. What can you then say about the solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$n+30=k\cdot 2n$$ so $$n=\frac{30}{2k-1}$$ where $k$ is a integer. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

The relation  can be written as 
$$n+30=2kn\iff 30=(2k-1)n\quad\text{for some }k,$$
in other words, $n$ is an *even* divisor of $30$. Can you find them?

Comment: I don't quite get it, sorry. Can you explain more please ?

Comment: What didn't you get?

Comment: I think I get the point now. Odd divisors of 30 are 1, 3 , 5 and 15 so the answer is 4. Thanks a lot

Comment: You forgot $15$.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I meant $n$ is the quotient of $30$ by an odd number, so $n$ is an *even* divisor of $30$.

Comment: Yes I noticed but you gave me the idea of the solution so thanks

Comment: You're welcome!